# JavaScript - meansure execution time of every command in browser console

Tags: javascript, console, profiling

Is there any way to meansure execution time of every command I put in browser js console?

So if I'd wrote:

```
> 2+2
```

and press enter It'd return something like `4 (executed in 1ms)`

And if I'd put something like

```
> myTimeExpensiveFunction();
```

It'd return like `true (executed in 238ms)`?

I know a lot of ways to do it with 2 extra lines of code on beginning and end of command, but I'm lazy and I don't want to add them every time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) and [`console.timeEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/timeEnd):

```
console.time('my name');
// my heavy duty stuff
console.log(2+2); // 4
console.timeEnd('my name'); // my name: 0.513ms
```

> **Non-standard**
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: It requires me to write 3 lines instead of 1 and that was actualy main point of my question to avoid it :)